# c# mono failing to call a public method in static instantiation

Tags: c#, mono

I have a thread that is basically the following.  The problem is Server is a public class and world is a static World instance which has a public void method called Tick().  Every time the worker thread calls Server.world.Tick() it falls into the catch block with a System.TypeLoadException has occured.

This code works fine on Windows with .NET 4.0 only failing on Mono debugging with Mono-Develop currently.

```
   while (!Server.shutdownServer)
        {
            try
            {
                Server.world.Tick();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
         }
```

As you can see. Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only thing we can see that you are eating exception instead at the very least logging it (and call stack) - there nothing can be said beyond your TypeLoadException without additional information.

Comment: Please provide a stacktrace and more info about the exception. Impossible to guess. Mono version would also be good to note.